# Correct inconsistent field values in an SQL Table

Tags: sql, replace, trim

I need to

- remove all leading and trailing spaces in the table
- clean up inconsistent values. For example, in the location column, a city showing up as *san fran* should be changed to *san Francisco*

Here is a copy of my current table :

> '3', 'McGavin', 'Darrin', 'San Diego, CA', **' captainlove@headfirsttheater.com'**, 'Cruise Ship Captain', 'M', '1966-01-23', 'single', 'sailing, fishing, yachting', 'women for casual relationships', NULL, NULL, NULL
>
> '11', 'Toth', 'Anne', **'San Fran, CA'**, 'Anne_Toth@leapinlimos.com', 'Artist', 'F', '1969-11-18', 'divorced', 'painting, classical music', 'casual friendship', NULL, NULL, NULL

I marked in bold what needs to be changed :

- in the first row, there is a space in front of the email *captainlove@...*
- in the second row, *san fran* needs to be changed to *San Francisco*, etc

**Disclaimer** : These are the exact directions (this is a school project so I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, I just need help)

I know I need to use the `TRIM` to get rid of the spaces and something like this for the *san fran* string `WHERE location LIKE 'san%' or location LIKE '_fran'`
The query works great but I just don't know how to tell it to replace what I want with the `REPLACE` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement, usually written as

```
UPDATE table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

For example, to trim your `email` field:

```
UPDATE your_table SET email=TRIM(email)
```

or for your `location` field with your condition

```
UPDATE tbl SET location='San Francisco, CA'
WHERE location LIKE 'san%' or location LIKE '_fran';
```

Running this last query will show you your condition is a bit too greedy : [see this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f0485/1/0)

Comment: great, got that working, now how would I add a second up date to change Palo to Palo Alto, but rather than write 2 updates, how can I combine the 2 into a single query/update

Comment: Here is the code i came up with to fix the 2 updates in one   UPDATE TABLE 
SET location='San Francisco, CA'
WHERE location like 'san%' or location like  '_fran'
set location='Palo Alto, CA'
WHERE location like 'pal%' or location like '_alto'                 but for some reason I am getting an error on the first line  "UPDATE TABLE"

Comment: @bodhi you can't stack the SET, the syntax doesn't support it. You will have to write multiple statements or use very convoluted IF to do what you want.

Comment: need to parse a string in one column called "location" and copy the contents of "city,state" into 2 new columns of "city" and "state", while leaving location as it is, is this even possible? Or should I just move the data? I have a substring_index that works fine when I use the SELECT, but I need to update the table. thanks in advance,  code ... I am close
UPDATE my_contacts SET 
location=substring_index(location, ', ',1) as city,
WHERE location='%%';

UPDATE my_contacts
SET location=substring_index(location, ', ',-1) as state
from my_contacts
WHERE location='%%';

Comment: Ask another question with that, it would really be easier to understand and answer